# Defining the schema type for a constructor in Java class

Tags: java, xmlbeans

I'm having a class like

```
public class CreditCardResponseDocumentImpl extends org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlComplexContentImpl implements creditcard.CreditCardResponseDocument
{

    public CreditCardResponseDocumentImpl(org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaType sType)
    {
        super(sType);
    }
}
```

While calling the constructor in a groovy file like

```
CreditCardResponseDocumentImpl creditCardResponseDocument = new CreditCardResponseDocumentImpl(<What parameter should I pass here>).
```

It's basically asking for (SchemaType sType)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Nizam

Answer (score 0):

If yo are created `parametrized` constructor you have to create `default constructor` also.

```
public class CreditCardResponseDocumentImpl extends org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlComplexContentImpl implements creditcard.CreditCardResponseDocument
{

 public CreditCardResponseDocumentImpl(){

    }

    public CreditCardResponseDocumentImpl(org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaType sType)
    {
        super(sType);
    }
}
```

If you are not calling your defaulat constructor then you have to pass SchemaType `sType`

Comment: Not certainly. It's not there in the class. Anyways, can you tell me what parameter should I pass there?

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to provide it a SchemaType, [here](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/xmlbeans/SchemaType.html) is the javadoc for it

> every XML Bean instance has an actual SchemaType, obtainable by
>   XmlObject#schemaType

I guess your `CreditCardResponseDocumentImpl` is an `XmlObject`